# Line return in php mail

Tags: php

I'm trying to force line breaks in a php mail function, but I'm not having any luck.
I tried two different methods, but neither seems to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$message_body = "<html><head></head><body>";
$message_body .= "<img src='path to image' alt='alt text' />\r\n";
$message_body .= "<span style='padding: 5px; background: #eee;'>" . " Visitor: " . $user_name . " </span>" . "\r\n\r\n" . $message . "</body></html>";
$headers = "From: " . $user_name . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

After the image, I want the visitor line to be on a line by itself & then the message on a line by itself.

Comment: You're using HTML content. You might try `<br>` or `<p></p>`.

Comment: Use `<br>` and/or `<p>` since you're already using HTML. Even a `<div>` will work. This is **HTML 101** stuff.

Comment: I would recommend using `<br>`

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remember :**

FOR PHP

Only within double quoted strings the escape sequences \r and \n are recognized
try concatenating `"\r\n"` in your string

FOR HTML

TRY concatenating `"<br>"` in your strings

Comment: I tried "\r\n" - didn't work, but <br /> did - thanks